# ValueError: The following `model_kwargs` are not used by the model: ['encoder_outputs'] (note: typos in the generate arguments will also show up

Tags: pytorch, ocr, transformer-model, encoder, encoder-decoder

When I try to run my  code for Donut for DocVQA model, I got the following error

```
"""Test"""
from donut import DonutModel
from PIL import Image
import torch

model = DonutModel.from_pretrained(
    "naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-cord-v2")
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.half()
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    model.to(device)
else:
    model.encoder.to(torch.bfloat16)
model.eval()
image = Image.open(
    "./src/png-report-page_capone_v1_August_2017_GMS_Balance_Sheet_0.png").convert("RGB")
output = model.inference(image=image, prompt="<s_cord-v2>")

print(output)
```

The error`

```
ValueError: The following `model_kwargs` are not used by the model: ['encoder_outputs'] (note: typos in the generate arguments will also show up in this list)
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the transformers library version.
For me, I reinstalled the 4.21.3 version and it worked.